# How to remove a tag from my TinyDB

Tags: app-inventor

I want to build an application that takes data from one screen and lists them on another screen. I use `TinyDB` to do this. My problem is **how to delete a tag?**

When I choose what to delete, it deletes it but if I get back to the screen from the beginning it shows the entire list without changes.

[I attach my blocks here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oprZ0.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Provide the code and the errors or the unexpected you are getting.

Comment: see also [your thread in the App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/6ZbiY5MKMdg/qmlTf1vkAwAJ)

Answer (score 0):

Your blocks look fine, your issue seems to be in the other screen...

In the other screen first read your tags from `TinyDB` again before displaying them... in case this does not help, you might want to edit your question and add a screenshot of the other screen, where it shows the entire list without changes...

Also: never use the open another screen block together with Screen1. Why? see here:
[The recommended method of switching screens in App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/manager.php)

Note: there is only one `TinyDB`, see also the [documentation](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/storage.html#TinyDB)

> Each app has its own data store. There is only one data store per app.
>   Even if you have multiple TinyDB components, they will use the same
>   data store. To get the effect of separate stores, use different keys.
>   You cannot use the TinyDB to pass data between two different apps on
>   the phone, although you can use the TinyDB to share data between the
>   different screens of a multi-screen app.

A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the [Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)